# Confused on java.util.ArrayList implementation

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Good day,

Here is the code inside my `java.util.ArrayList`:

```
@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
    int localLastIndex = lastIndex;
    Object[] dumpArray = collection.toArray();
    if (dumpArray.length == 0) { /this is line 244
        return false;
    }
    if (dumpArray.length > array.length - localLastIndex) { //this is line 247
        localLastIndex = growAtEnd(dumpArray.length, localLastIndex);
    }
    System.arraycopy(dumpArray, 0, this.array, localLastIndex,
            dumpArray.length);
    localLastIndex += dumpArray.length;
    modCount++;
    lastIndex = localLastIndex;
    return true;
}
```

And here is my error log: I'm getting a null pointer exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:247) ~[na:na]
```

At line 247, I believe `dumpArray` will not be null, if it is null, then it will hit null pointer exception early at line 244 because the line already uses `dumpArray`.

If dumpArray is null, why is addAll() throwing the exception at line 247 if it could have thrown the exception earlier? That is, if dumpArray is null, then shouldn't

```
    if (dumpArray.length == 0) { /this is line 244
```

already have thrown the exception?

Here is my code:

```
    List< FixedDepositReceiptDetail > receipts = new ArrayList< FixedDepositReceiptDetail >( );

    while ( response.isMoreRecords( ) ) {
       receipts.addAll( response.getReceipts( ) );
    }
```

here is my full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:247) ~[na:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.eai.impl.AccountQueryServiceImpl.getFixedDepositDetail(AccountQueryServiceImpl.java:239) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.eai.impl.AccountQueryServiceImpl.getAccountDetail(AccountQueryServiceImpl.java:158) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.app.account.command.AccountDetailsCommandHandler.execute(AccountDetailsCommandHandler.java:57) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.app.account.command.AccountDetailsCommandHandler.execute(AccountDetailsCommandHandler.java:1) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at com.cv.common.command.CommandExecutor.doExecute(CommandExecutor.java:50) ~[com.cv.common.jar:na]
    at com.cv.common.command.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:44) ~[com.cv.common.jar:na]
    at com.cv.common.command.LocalCommandHandler.execute(LocalCommandHandler.java:46) ~[com.cv.common.jar:na]
    at com.cv.common.command.LocalCommandHandler.execute(LocalCommandHandler.java:1) ~[com.cv.common.jar:na]
    at com.cv.common.command.CommandTemplate.execute(CommandTemplate.java:33) ~[com.cv.common.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.app.account.ui.AbstractAccountAction.detail(AbstractAccountAction.java:408) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper$6.intercept(DispatcherHelper.java:442) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:158) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.common.ui.interceptor.JSTokenInterceptor.intercept(JSTokenInterceptor.java:60) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.common.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at org.stripesstuff.plugin.session.SessionStoreInterceptor.intercept(SessionStoreInterceptor.java:52) ~[stripesstuff-0.1.jar:74M]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.audit.ui.interceptor.BaseAuditLogInterceptor.intercept(BaseAuditLogInterceptor.java:109) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.audit.ui.interceptor.BaseAuditLogInterceptor.intercept(BaseAuditLogInterceptor.java:109) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.audit.ui.interceptor.BaseAuditLogInterceptor.intercept(BaseAuditLogInterceptor.java:109) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.common.ui.interceptor.TokenInterceptor.intercept(TokenInterceptor.java:122) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.common.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.intercept(BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.java:113) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.wrap(ExecutionContext.java:74) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper.invokeEventHandler(DispatcherHelper.java:440) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.invokeEventHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:285) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.doPost(DispatcherServlet.java:167) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.doGet(DispatcherServlet.java:67) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575) ~[javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) ~[javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:246) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:246) ~[stripes-1.5_cv.jar:955]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129) [sitemesh-2.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77) [sitemesh-2.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.common.security.filter.AOBAuthenticationProcessFilter.doFilterHttp(AOBAuthenticationProcessFilter.java:99) [com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.common.security.context.SecurityContextDetailsFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextDetailsFilter.java:44) [com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188) [spring-security-core-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) [org.springframework.web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [org.springframework.web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.common.ui.filter.MetaContextFactoryFilter.doFilter(MetaContextFactoryFilter.java:61) [com.cv.ibs.cib.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125) [displaytag-1.2.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.cv.common.web.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:65) [com.cv.common.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.cv.common.web.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:65) [com.cv.common.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.common.ui.filter.MDCInfoCaptureFilter.doFilter(MDCInfoCaptureFilter.java:92) [com.cv.ibs.cib.common.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.cib.common.ui.filter.MDCInfoCaptureFilter.doFilter(MDCInfoCaptureFilter.java:92) [com.cv.ibs.cib.common.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:461) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:528) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:314) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: What JDK implementation are you using?

Comment: Can you post the code that initialises your arraylist?

Comment: where and how is `array` initialized?

Comment: Also, it seems you didn't read the rest of the stacktrace. I'm pretty sure java.util.ArrayList is not the real cause.

Comment: @haggisandchips, I am using JDK 1.6

Comment: @morbidCode, Just upload my code.

Comment: @Panadol Chong I mean your getReceipts() method code

Comment: `if (dumpArray.length > array.length - localLastIndex) ` What is `array` in `array.length` ? I suspect this one is null

Comment: @morbidCode, my getReceipts() method is just a simple get set method. As I know, even my getReceipts() method return null, I am suppose to hit error at line 243 instead of line 247, right?

Comment: @BrunoGrieder, the `array` is actually equal to `receipts` list object. If it is null, then I should hit null pointer exception at early, but not go in to `addAll()` method only hit null pointer exception.

Comment: @PanadolChong then if `array` is `receipts` why do you use `array`and not `this` in method `addAll` ?

Comment: @Panadol Chong can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Can you give the exact jdk version you are using? For example in jdk1.6.0_39 the line 247 of ArrayList.java is a comment line.

Comment: I think you need to quote the JDK vendor as well - so far I cannot find the ArrayList source that relates to your question.

Comment: Seems to be IBM implementation. By the way, I'm not sure that he deserves the downvotes...

Comment: @Dani agreed, but the question is a little bit unclear. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Panadol Chong I tried to edit the question to make it clearer. Hope this helps you.

Comment: @PanadolChong the likelihood there is a bug in the actual JDK ArrayList is astronomically low compared the probability of a bug in your code.  Almost certainly, either your `ArrayList` is null or the thing you are passing to `addAll` is null.

Comment: I have to agree with @louis-wasserman. Your use case suggests that this would be occurring regularly for thousands upon thousands of people. My suspicion is that you have the wrong source code and the passed collection is what is null. Have you tried debugging your code so that you can verify your source matches up and that would also allow you to verify the exception is being thrown at the line you think - or rather that line 247 is what you think it is.

Comment: Probably you are looking at a version of `ArrayList.java` from a different release and the line numbers are of by 4, so that line 247 is `Object[] dumpArray = collection.toArray();`. A `NullPointerException` is thrown on this line if you pass `null` to `addAll`